# Cargar clase Imagine en Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend

Para cargar la clase `Imagine` a un controlador ejecuté la siguiente línea en el terminal: `composer require imagine/imagine`

Lo cual, en la carpeta `vendor` creo una carpeta llamada `imagine` con muchas clases.

Luego en el archivo "Module.php" de mi controlador agregué la siguiente función:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
        'image_service' => 'Imagine\Gd\Imagine',
    ));
}
```

En mi IndexController.php coloco está línea

```
$imagine = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('image_service');
```

Y me da error:

> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::createFromInvokable: failed
>   retrieving "imageservice(alias: image_service)" via invokable class
>   "Imagine\Gd\Imagine"; class does not exist

Lo más terrible, es que en mi localhost funciona lo más bien y no da error, pero en el servidor da el error.

Comment: El código mostrado está correcto. Por descartar, ¿has probado a instanciar la clase directamente en el controlador? `$imagine = new \Imagine\Gd\Imagine();` En el proyecto que tiene en local, ¿también tienes `php7`?

Comment: Sí, lo hice y da error, pero con página en blanco.

Lo que hice fue hacer una instalación nueva de todo ZF2, instale `Imagine` y dentro de esta copie el módulo que ocupa la clase, luego lo subí al servidor y funciono sin problema. Creo que es un problema desde cuando empece a programar el sistema. 

Seguiré buscando, muchas gracias @Oscar R.

Comment: ¿También ocurre si instancias cualquier otra clase que esté dentro de `vendor`?

Comment: Lo más probable es que la instalación inicial de mi proyecto quedo con problemas. Lo que hice fue que los módulos los copie y pegue en la instalación nueva, lo probe y funcionó sin problemas en el local y en el servidor.